# Can you query SharePoint in C# using SQL?

Tags: 2007, development, document-library

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but I cannot find an answer.  Can you query a SharePoint Document Library or site in a C# program using SQL?

If so, how do you set up the connection to SharePoint with C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you are planning to query a SharePoint database, please don't do that! It's not supported and wrong in many ways.

You should use [SharePoint APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550992%28office.12%29.aspx) to retrieve data you need. You can retrieve items from a SharePoint list via [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist%28office.12%29.aspx) object (not optimal for large list), or if you plan to query a list you should use [CAML](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list).

Comment: All the answers were helpful, but the links in your's really helped, thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use FullTextSQLQuery to issue SQL-like queries against the search index.

For simply returning a list of items, the standard is to use CAML queries, or LINQ to SharePoint is quickly becoming a popular method of doing this now.

Never attempt to directly query the underlying SQL content database, as this is not a supported practice.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add my $2 on why you shouldn't connect directly to the SQL DB (and should use the SharePoint API as others have said), I blogged about this here: [Supported Database Operations in SharePoint 2010.](http://mossblogger.blogspot.com/2010/06/administration-supported-database.html)

Comment: much more deserved +1